# Lab environment, allow ssh version 1

Tags: linux, ssh

When trying to access a Cisco VM router in a GNS3 environment I'm getting the error: `SSH protocol v.1 is no longer supported` when I'm using the command `sshpass -p Cisco ssh Cisco@192.168.224.7 -1`.

I think I can edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to allow this but unsure of the option to do so. Is there either way to force ssh version 1?

This is just a lab, yes it's insecure, I don't care. I want to force this to make something I'm doing easier. Is there an ssh program in Linux that does just this or can I edit the configuration file to force to allow version 1?

Also, this is a Ubuntu VM that I'm using to try to ssh into this Cisco VM router, its actually WSL v2.

Comment: Modern versions of OpenSSH have dropped support for protocol v1 specifically because it's insecure, so the answer is that you probably can't do that.  Also, it seems a bit odd to come to Information Security Stack Exchange and specifically ask about how to do something that's insecure without caring about its security.

Comment: I was not aware that I was in the internet security section, sorry about this. Yes I'm aware its insecure, don't care. I'm creating these VM for minutes at a time for ansible and learning sessions. I'll try to find the proper section, thanks bk2204.

Comment: What does `show ip ssh` show?

Comment: R1(config)#do show ip ssh
SSH Enabled - version 1.5
Authentication timeout: 60 secs; Authentication retries: 2
Minimum expected Diffie Hellman key size : 1024 bits
IOS Keys in SECSH format(ssh-rsa, base64 encoded):
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAQQCiKFVorqnkdAZtZ0N98t6vLCUz8z7iEDuWi5TDrXZN
BLAhhigP6p9qlpLnEjLDi8LaFpC0sdY0YRJiHbMUKNYz

Comment: Odd it says version 1.5

Comment: The problem I'm experiencing is that I can turn ssh to v2 with command "crypto key generate rsa usage-keys label sshkey modulus 768" or even 800+ bits but then I get this issue:

"root@G-GamingPC:/etc/ansible# sshpass -p Cisco ssh Cisco@192.168.224.7"
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.224.7 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Comment: That looks like a different problem/question.

Answer (score 3):

SSHv1 support was completely removed in OpenSSH version 7.6. There's no option to "force" or "reenable" it – the SSHv1 code literally no longer *exists* within the `ssh` program. (Unless you keep an old version around.)

As you mention in comments, your router does actually support SSHv2, just with an outdated set of algorithms. You *can* re-enable some of them in modern OpenSSH versions, with an ~/.ssh/config similar to this:

```
Host 192.168.224.7
    Ciphers +aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

But to access old systems in general, you can use the `plink` client from PuTTY which supports SSHv1 and many obsolete SSHv2 ciphers (yes, it has a [native Linux version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/putty-tools)) – or just `telnet` into the router instead.

```
plink Cisco@192.168.224.7
```

(You don't need sshpass for it, because plink already has the `-pw` option to specify a password.)

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, pass `-1` flag to ssh which forces ssh to try protocol version 1 only.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh

You may need to downgrade the router to allow version 1 ssh. It's likely set to allow version 2 only. Try `ip ssh version 1` to allow version 1.

Comment: The OP already said they tried `-1`.